# payload for POST and PUT methods in swagger

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, drf-yasg

im using yasg library for make a doc for my apis..
but i have a problem:
GET and DELETE methods are fine but when i want use POST or PUT method i cant define payload for them..
in parameters section it says:  No parameters
this is my code :

```
class CreateGroupView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = GroupSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except:
            return Response({'data': 'somethings wrong'}, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from drf_yasg import openapi
from drf_yasg.utils import swagger_auto_schema

type_param = openapi.Parameter('type', in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, description='Type parameter', type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER)
q_param = openapi.Parameter('q', in_=openapi.IN_QUERY, description='Seach query', type=openapi.TYPE_STRING)

class CreateGroupView(APIView):

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        responses={status.HTTP_201_CREATED: GroupSerializer()},
        operation_description="Some description here...",
        manual_parameters=[type_param, q_param]
    )
    def post(self, request):
        try:
            serializer = GroupSerializer(data=request.data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        except:
            return Response({'data': 'somethings wrong'}, status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: this is good.this shows required fields in response section..but is there any way to have something like this in parameters section due to test that method with its parameters?

Comment: I think `manual parameters` is what you need. I've updated the answer.

Comment: dude i tested this and it doesnt work..it shows me parameters but when i want fill them i revieved error (invalid_data)...

Comment: Update your question. Post your serializer and parameters you need